# Boolean mini Python program to play hangman

Tags: python-3.x, boolean-logic

I'm trying to create a program to play hangman, and it's broken into multiple small chunks. This particular chunk is supposed to return 'True' if the letters of the secret word are within the letters guessed, and false if at least one of the letters of the secret word is not in the letters guessed. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because my code isn't consistently turning out the right answer. Thank you for your help!

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter not in lettersGuessed:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your loop is returning `True` on the first `letter` in `lettersGuessed`. You need to loop through all of the letters before returning `True`, e.g.:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter not in lettersGuessed:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

In this particular circumstance you don't need the `else:` clause on the `for` loop as this is equivalent to:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter not in lettersGuessed:
            return False
    return True
```

Or you can use the `all()` function:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    return all(letter in lettersGuessed for letter in secretWord)
```